# What kind of resource is __TFE12CoreGraphicsVSC6CGRectCfMS0_FT1xSi1ySi5widthSi6heightSi_S0_?

Tags: ios

My iPhone crashlog (and not my Simulator) shows me that I have the following issue:

```
Dyld Error Message:
    Symbol not found: __TFE12CoreGraphicsVSC6CGRectCfMS0_FT1xSi1ySi5widthSi6heightSi_S0_
    Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8F97818E-F019-42E8-883C-6FB1994C24B7/Ekalipi.app/PlugIns/EkalipiKeyboard.appex/EkalipiKeyboard
    Expected in: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8F97818E-F019-42E8-883C-6FB1994C24B7/Ekalipi.app/PlugIns/EkalipiKeyboard.appex/../../Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
    Dyld Version: 353.5
```

Is this a Unicode symbol that can't be loaded?

Last meaningful stack entry is this:

```
6   EkalipiKeyboard                 0x0010ad88 0xf5000 + 89480
7   UIKit                           0x2acbe4f0 -[_UIViewServiceViewControllerOperator __createViewController:withContextToken:fbsDisplays:appearanceSerializedRepresentations:legacyAppearance:hostAccessibilityServerPort:canShowTextServices:replyHandler:] + 1152
```

What is the pattern for understanding the above resource string?

Many thanks in advance!
Klaus

Comment: It's a name mangled one :-) Looks like a CGRect. Check out this article (by Gwynne Raskind) on Mike Ash's blog for more info on name mangling in swift. https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-08-15-swift-name-mangling.html It has a comprehensive breakdown on how to decypher the mangled names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a mangled label that the compiler generated for that function (the CGRect initializer)

You can break down the full label like this (I think)

```
__TFE12CoreGraphicsVSC6CGRectCfMS0_FT1xSi1ySi5widthSi6heightSi_S0_
```

- `_` is a common beginning of a symbol
- `_T` is the marker for a Swift global symbol
- `F` says that it's a function
- I don't know what `E` means (but looking at the detangled symbol it seems to correspond to `ext`)
- `12CoreGraphics` is the name of the module (prefixes with the length of the name)
- `V` marks the start of a struct
- I don't know what `S` or what `C` means
- `6CGRect` is the name of the function (I think it's the function)
- I don't know what `C` means (see M below)
- `f` marks this symbol as an "uncurried function"
- I don't know what `M` means (`CfM` together seem to mean an `init` function but I don't know what the individual letters mean)
- `S0_` is a substitution. I think it's a substitution for "self" which is passed to curry the function
- `F` here marks the beginning of the function's parameter list
- `T` marks the beginning of a "tuple" (for the arguments)
- `1x` is the name of the first parameter (prefixed with the length of the name)
- `Si` says that it is of the Swift.Int type
- `1y` is the name of the second parameter (prefixed with the length of the name)
- `Si` says that it is of the Swift.Int type
- `5width` is the name of the third parameter (prefixed with the length of the name)
- `Si` says that it is of the Swift.Int type
- `6height` is the name of the fourth parameter (prefixed with the length of the name)
- `Si` says that it is of the Swift.Int type
- `_` marks the end of the uncurried function's arguments tuple
- `S0_` is the same substitution again (which I think means that it returns "self")

---

Additionally, running it through `xcrun swift-demangle` gives the official demangling:

`ext.CoreGraphics.C.CGRect.init (C.CGRect.Type)(x : Swift.Int, y : Swift.Int, width : Swift.Int, height : Swift.Int) -> C.CGRect`

---

Gwynne Raskind wrote a very detailed article about [Swift Name Mangling](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-08-15-swift-name-mangling.html) where you can read more about this name mangling

Comment: Wow, that is a detailed answer! Thanks a lot. I learned something here.